# Heroku -Kafka Connect - H10 , R15, R10

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to pipeline Heroku Postgres to Kafka , kafkaconnect to snowflake.

I had all the attributes set in connect.distributed.properties file.

But getting Error for H10, R15, R10 from the below Heroku Logs.

Guide me to resolve this.

Heroku Logs are given below for references . I couldn't pasted complete logs for the reason of limitation in pasting here in this forum.

```
2021-02-04T00:03:42.454319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T00:03:42.465041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-04T00:03:47.023721+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 3 messages since 2021-02-04T00:02:47.157222+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:03:49.488380+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 2 messages since 2021-02-04T00:02:49.622107+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:03:57.689377+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 2 messages since 2021-02-04T00:02:57.822658+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:04:05.605070+00:00 heroku[run.2011]: source=run.2011 dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.d0a2e5b2-05ab-4e37-b81a-76b3a670c8ac sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2021-02-04T00:04:05.605979+00:00 heroku[run.2011]: source=run.2011 dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.d0a2e5b2-05ab-4e37-b81a-76b3a670c8ac sample#memory_total=18.77MB sample#memory_rss=10.76MB sample#memory_cache=6.87MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=2148pages sample#memory_pgpgout=189pages sample#memory_quota=2560.00MB
2021-02-04T00:04:05.855980+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 5 messages since 2021-02-04T00:03:06.092064+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:04:06.464579+00:00 app[web.1]: sfsc-kafka-c1-test
2021-02-04T00:04:06.464657+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== sfsc-kafka-c1-test =====
2021-02-04T00:04:06.464724+00:00 app[web.1]: Client Cert Key: CK-
2021-02-04T00:04:06.464775+00:00 app[web.1]: Client Cert: TP-
2021-02-04T00:04:06.464816+00:00 app[web.1]: Trusted Cert: KP-
2021-02-04T00:04:06.471250+00:00 app[web.1]: No Error while creating .pem files
2021-02-04T00:04:06.471252+00:00 app[web.1]: keystore - $ /etc/kafka/keystore.pem
2021-02-04T00:04:06.471292+00:00 app[web.1]: trusted - $ /etc/kafka/truststore.pem
2021-02-04T00:04:06.792240+00:00 app[web.1]: Certificate was added to keystore
2021-02-04T00:04:06.806985+00:00 app[web.1]: unable to write 'random state'
2021-02-04T00:04:06.988712+00:00 app[web.1]: Importing keystore /etc/kafka/keystore.pkcs12 to /etc/kafka/keystore.jks...
2021-02-04T00:04:07.229811+00:00 app[web.1]: Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.
2021-02-04T00:04:07.232028+00:00 app[web.1]: Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
2021-02-04T00:04:07.233344+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.233389+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning:
2021-02-04T00:04:07.233511+00:00 app[web.1]: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /etc/kafka/keystore.jks -destkeystore /etc/kafka/keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
2021-02-04T00:04:07.261163+00:00 app[web.1]: * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
2021-02-04T00:04:07.263708+00:00 app[web.1]:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2021-02-04T00:04:07.264877+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2021-02-04T00:04:07.326777+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.327743+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.328101+00:00 app[web.1]: * successfully set certificate verify locations:
2021-02-04T00:04:07.328101+00:00 app[web.1]: *   CAfile: none
2021-02-04T00:04:07.328104+00:00 app[web.1]:   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
2021-02-04T00:04:07.328273+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.328274+00:00 app[web.1]: } [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.331949+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.331950+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.331988+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.331989+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.332909+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.332910+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333130+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333131+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333789+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333790+00:00 app[web.1]: } [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333818+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333819+00:00 app[web.1]: } [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333941+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.333941+00:00 app[web.1]: } [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.334954+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.334988+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335092+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335124+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335150+00:00 app[web.1]: * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335151+00:00 app[web.1]: * Server certificate:
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335181+00:00 app[web.1]: *   subject: CN=sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335221+00:00 app[web.1]: *   start date: 2021-01-04 16:52:40 GMT
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335221+00:00 app[web.1]: *   expire date: 2021-04-04 16:52:40 GMT
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335222+00:00 app[web.1]: *   subjectAltName: sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com matched
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335245+00:00 app[web.1]: *   issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335245+00:00 app[web.1]: *   SSL certificate verify ok.
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335424+00:00 app[web.1]: > POST /connectors HTTP/1.1
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335424+00:00 app[web.1]: > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335425+00:00 app[web.1]: > Host: sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335425+00:00 app[web.1]: > Accept: */*
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335425+00:00 app[web.1]: > Content-Type: application/json
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335426+00:00 app[web.1]: > Content-Length: 41
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335426+00:00 app[web.1]: > 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335468+00:00 app[web.1]: } [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:07.335469+00:00 app[web.1]: * upload completely sent off: 41 out of 41 bytes
2021-02-04T00:04:07.248703+00:00 app[web.1]: Variables: kafka-dimensional-99909:-KAFKA kafka-dimensional-99909:-KAFKA_PREFIX kafka-dimensional-99909:-KAFKA_PREFIX kafka-dimensional-99909:-KAFKA_URL postgresql-graceful-54180:-DATABASE 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.248748+00:00 app[web.1]: Secuirty protocal: H-/app TP-ReM{Fk[3s~<3<2T7 KP-N!C@NE8br7't9MG%
2021-02-04T00:04:07.248802+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== After postgres_addon_name =====
2021-02-04T00:04:07.250942+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== After CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC =====
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251010+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== Before PORT =====
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251067+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== After PORT =====
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251180+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== After CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH =====
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251231+00:00 app[web.1]: ============Starting Process========= 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251520+00:00 app[web.1]:  Server URL https://sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com 
2021-02-04T00:04:07.251582+00:00 app[web.1]: Heroku Port - 9092
2021-02-04T00:04:07.256739+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> User
2021-02-04T00:04:07.258718+00:00 app[web.1]: uid=3061(dyno) gid=3061(dyno) groups=3061(dyno)
2021-02-04T00:04:07.258990+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> Configuring ...
2021-02-04T00:04:11.097695+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> Running preflight checks ... 
2021-02-04T00:04:11.100407+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> Check if Kafka is healthy ...
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642347+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642351+00:00 app[web.1]:    client.dns.lookup = default
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642352+00:00 app[web.1]:    client.id = 
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642352+00:00 app[web.1]:    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642353+00:00 app[web.1]:    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642353+00:00 app[web.1]:    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642353+00:00 app[web.1]:    metric.reporters = []
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642354+00:00 app[web.1]:    metrics.num.samples = 2
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642354+00:00 app[web.1]:    metrics.recording.level = INFO
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642354+00:00 app[web.1]:    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642355+00:00 app[web.1]:    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642355+00:00 app[web.1]:    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642355+00:00 app[web.1]:    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642356+00:00 app[web.1]:    request.timeout.ms = 30000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642356+00:00 app[web.1]:    retries = 2147483647
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642356+00:00 app[web.1]:    retry.backoff.ms = 100
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642356+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642357+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.jaas.config = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642357+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642357+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642358+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642358+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642358+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642358+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642358+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.class = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642359+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642359+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642359+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642360+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642360+00:00 app[web.1]:    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642360+00:00 app[web.1]:    security.protocol = SSL
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642360+00:00 app[web.1]:    security.providers = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642360+00:00 app[web.1]:    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642361+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.cipher.suites = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642362+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642362+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642362+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642363+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642363+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.keystore.location = /etc/kafka/keystore.jks
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642363+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642363+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642364+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.protocol = TLS
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642364+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.provider = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642364+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642364+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642364+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.truststore.location = /etc/kafka/truststore.jks
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642365+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642365+00:00 app[web.1]:    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2021-02-04T00:04:11.642380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:11.895510+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.895666+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.895808+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.895950+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896089+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'internal.key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896244+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896385+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896525+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.key.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896695+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'status.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896820+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.key.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.896917+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897010+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'offset.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897110+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897218+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897309+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897389+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897482+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897564+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897650+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897740+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'config.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897828+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897928+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'rest.advertised.host.name' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.897990+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'status.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898085+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898162+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'config.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898250+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898328+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'rest.port' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898401+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.keystore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898472+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'internal.key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898555+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898639+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'ssl.keystore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898704+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'internal.value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898781+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.key.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898857+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'internal.value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.898943+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'offset.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.899017+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'consumer.ssl.keystore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.899082+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - The configuration 'producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2021-02-04T00:04:11.901664+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 5.5.3-ccs
2021-02-04T00:04:11.901747+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 4cb2620286ad0b06
2021-02-04T00:04:11.901838+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1612397051899
2021-02-04T00:04:12.931322+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> Launching ... 
2021-02-04T00:04:12.936349+00:00 app[web.1]: ===> Launching kafka-connect ... 
2021-02-04T00:04:13.416942+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-04 00:04:13,416] INFO WorkerInfo values: 
2021-02-04T00:04:13.416953+00:00 app[web.1]:    jvm.args = -Xms256M, -Xmx2G, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties
2021-02-04T00:04:13.416954+00:00 app[web.1]:    jvm.spec = Azul Systems, Inc., OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_222, 25.222-b10
2021-02-04T00:04:13.417241+00:00 app[web.1]:    os.spec = Linux, amd64, 4.4.0-1082-aws
2021-02-04T00:04:13.417241+00:00 app[web.1]:    os.vcpus = 2
2021-02-04T00:04:13.417242+00:00 app[web.1]:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.336739+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:37.336845+00:00 app[web.1]: < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
2021-02-04T00:04:37.336940+00:00 app[web.1]: < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
2021-02-04T00:04:37.337045+00:00 app[web.1]: < Via: 1.1 spaces-router (3bba204e6224)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.337134+00:00 app[web.1]: < Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2021 00:04:37 GMT
2021-02-04T00:04:37.337238+00:00 app[web.1]: < Content-Length: 561
2021-02-04T00:04:37.337324+00:00 app[web.1]: < 
2021-02-04T00:04:37.337934+00:00 app[web.1]: { [data not shown]
2021-02-04T00:04:37.344816+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:37.344951+00:00 app[web.1]: * Connection #0 to host sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com left intact
2021-02-04T00:04:37.336106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/connectors" host=sfsc-kafka-c1-test.herokuapp.com request_id=67d1ae35-b126-7419-19de-b7d044b4f40a fwd="" dyno= connect=0ms service=0ms status=503 bytes=561 protocol=http tls_version=tls1.2
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345018+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345019+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345020+00:00 app[web.1]:   <head>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345020+00:00 app[web.1]:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345021+00:00 app[web.1]:     <meta charset="utf-8">
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345021+00:00 app[web.1]:     <title>Application Error</title>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345021+00:00 app[web.1]:     <style media="screen">
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345021+00:00 app[web.1]:       html,body,iframe {
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345022+00:00 app[web.1]:         margin: 0;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345022+00:00 app[web.1]:         padding: 0;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345022+00:00 app[web.1]:       }
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345023+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345023+00:00 app[web.1]:       html,body {
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345023+00:00 app[web.1]:         height: 100%;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345023+00:00 app[web.1]:         overflow: hidden;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345024+00:00 app[web.1]:       }
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345024+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345024+00:00 app[web.1]:       iframe {
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345024+00:00 app[web.1]:         width: 100%;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345025+00:00 app[web.1]:         height: 100%;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345025+00:00 app[web.1]:         border: 0;
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345025+00:00 app[web.1]:       }
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345026+00:00 app[web.1]:     </style>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345026+00:00 app[web.1]:   </head>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345026+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345026+00:00 app[web.1]:     <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.345027+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2021-02-04T00:04:37.709954+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>[2021-02-04 00:04:37,709] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.802434+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-04 00:04:37,802] INFO Loading plugin from: /etc/kafka/secrets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.819945+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-04 00:04:37,819] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/etc/kafka/secrets/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.820402+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-04 00:04:37,820] INFO Loading plugin from: /etc/kafka/kafka-logs (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
2021-02-04T00:04:37.821602+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-04 00:04:37,821] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/etc/kafka/kafka-logs/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
2021-02-04T00:04:38.866299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2021-02-04T00:05:05.605040+00:00 heroku[run.2011]: source=run.2011 dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.d0a2e5b2-05ab-4e37-b81a-76b3a670c8ac sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2021-02-04T00:05:05.605642+00:00 heroku[run.2011]: source=run.2011 dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.d0a2e5b2-05ab-4e37-b81a-76b3a670c8ac sample#memory_total=18.77MB sample#memory_rss=10.76MB sample#memory_cache=6.87MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=2148pages sample#memory_pgpgout=189pages sample#memory_quota=2560.00MB
2021-02-04T00:05:07.578783+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 1 messages since 2021-02-04T00:04:27.704572+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:05:07.301542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.ae89842e-4431-4db2-be88-b6155640a3e5 source=web.1 sample#load_avg_1m=0.67 sample#load_avg_5m=0.22 sample#load_avg_15m=0.08
2021-02-04T00:05:07.302456+00:00 heroku[web.1]: dyno=heroku.049be91d-2b0a-44c6-b1ee-6fd6a30819e1.ae89842e-4431-4db2-be88-b6155640a3e5 source=web.1 sample#memory_total=7.46MB sample#memory_rss=3.31MB sample#memory_cache=0.29MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=546097pages sample#memory_pgpgout=545688pages sample#memory_quota=1024.00MB
2021-02-04T00:05:13.736618+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.7ecac605-b970-4a84-ac22-04552f489cd9' dropped 3 messages since 2021-02-04T00:04:13.870252+00:00.
2021-02-04T00:05:21.390975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

2021-02-04T00:05:22.426069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T00:05:22.436339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Comment: You didn't include logs. More context would help too

Comment: Hi Felipe, Pasted here with heroku logs...